# ¿Como puedo instalar paquetes npm con una conexion a internet inestable?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, webpack

Lo que paso: Intento instalar el paquete de webpack y webpack-cli en entorno de desarrollo local pero seguido me aparece el mensaje de error:

`npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack (over 30000ms)`

Asumo que se debe a una conexión lenta me conecte mediante cable y continua con el mismo resultado.

En caso logra conectar y comienza con el proceso **fetch** de descarga no dura nada y vuelve al mismo error. Con el error es casi imposible volver a descargar porque cuando se intenta volver a instalar existe un **JSON** de razón variedad en algún paquete que vota error, se entiende que por interrupción de red los archivos descargados no están completos o están corrompidos.

Desearía saber como puedo o desactivar un tiempo de espera o alargarlo mas de los 30s (30000ms) ya que el problema de conexión persistirá, es propia de la ISP que tengo como proveedor.

Datos de version:

- Node.js: v12.16.3 (estable)
- Npm: v6.14.4

Comment: Hola. Parece que mas que un problema de conexion lenta es que no tienes conexion. No soy muy conocedor, pero aunque la conexión sea lenta debería permitirte descargar. Si usas windows intenta desactivar el firewall para probar si descarga. Después lo reactivas y comentas como te va.

Comment: ¿Estás en una conexión directa o detrás de un proxy? ¿Puedes probar introduciendo el url (https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack) desde un browser y ver si te responde?

Answer (score 1):

El error no solo podría ser el tiempo de esperar rechazado si no un conjunto de inconvenientes. Pero si afirmas que el problema surge de allí podemos intentar lo siguientes. 
 
Solo bastaría con agregar mas tiempo y quizás actualizar los registros y el cache.

```
npm cache clean --force
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set loglevel info
npm config set fetch-retries 3
npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 15000
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 90000
npm config set cache-min 86400
```

Ingrese las lineas de comando en el orden publicado.

Si el problema persiste es necesario degradar una versión de `npm`. A partir de un posible fallo en su versión. [Vease aquí.](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1185)

```
npm i -g npm@6.13.7
```